# Getting useful debugging info from dynamic types

Tags: c#, debugging, dynamic

I'm working on a codebase that makes heavy use of `dynamic` types and it's getting increasingly difficult to find out exactly what is being created and passed around. Even when debugging and examining types of interest I'm getting "No further information on this object could be discovered" messages pretty much as soon as I examine the Dynamic View, which isn't helping. Are there any useful tricks to help me learn more about some of the types and properties hidden behind the `dynamic` black magic?

Comment: Have you considered reducing your reliance on `dynamic` types?

Comment: You don't know exactly how much I would love to do that - it wasn't my decision to introduce them. Basically, the site is built atop Orchard, which makes heavy use of them. I'm trying to deliver functionality for the business in a codebase that is rife with dynamic type magic. I have to work with it and try to understand how to deal with it

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with my custom dynamic class inherited from `DynamicObject`. Solution was to override `public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames()` to return the list of members. In my case all members are contained in dictionary so I did following:

```
    public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames()
    {
        return properties.Keys;
    }
```